Parquet file schema problem with package xitongsys/parquet-go
type TempoTrace struct {
 TraceIDText  string
 DurationNano int64
 StartTimeUnixNano int64
 RS []resourceSpan
}

 type resourceSpan struct {
    Resource Resource
    ScopeSpan []ScopeSpan
 }

type Resource struct {
   ServiceName string
}

This is my struct from parquet file. And this is my json schema:
{
   "Tag":"name=parquet_go_root, repetitiontype=REQUIRED",
   "Fields":[
      {
         "Tag":"name=TraceIDText, inname=TraceIDText, type=BYTE_ARRAY"
      },
      {
         "Tag":"name=DurationNano, inname=DurationNano, type=INT64"
      },
      {
         "Tag":"name=RS, inname=rs, type=LIST, repetitiontype=REQUIRED",
         "Fields":[
            {
               "Tag":"name=element, repetitiontype=REQUIRED",
               "Fields":[
                  {
                     "Tag":"name=Resource, inname=Resource, repetitiontype=REQUIRED",
                     "Fields":[
                        {
                           "Tag":"name=ServiceName, inname=ServiceName, type=BYTE_ARRAY"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

The problem is when i want to create parquet reader i got this error:

Can't create parquet reader [NextRowGroup] Column not found:
Parquet_go_rootRsListElementResourceServiceName

Does anyone know how to create schema for Resource struct. Btw with github.com/segmentio/parquet-go everything work but i need support for gcs...
segmentio implementation:
type TempoTrace struct {
    TraceIDText       string         `parquet:"TraceIDText"`
    DurationNano      int64          `parquet:"DurationNano"`
    RootServiceName   string         `parquet:"RootServiceName"`
    StartTimeUnixNano int64          `parquet:"StartTimeUnixNano"`
    EndTimeUnixNano   int64          `parquet:"EndTimeUnixNano"`
    RootSpanName      string         `parquet:"RootSpanName"`
    RS                []resourceSpan `parquet:"rs,list"`
}

type resourceSpan struct {
    Resource  Resource    `parquet:"Resource"`
}

type Resource struct {
    ServiceName string `parquet:"ServiceName"`
}

